# When to use “que”, “qui” or “qu'”?

Tags: pronoms, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

Which word (*que*, *qui*, *qu'*) would best fill the blank and why:

Il a attendu un bus ______ n'est jamais arrivé.

I'm a little confused with interrogative pronouns.

Comment: You are good to go with qu'. because the next letter is a consonant.

Comment: Qu' only instead of que before a vowel. So not in your case where the next word is consonant-initial and the pronoun should be qui. This form is used in informal French also for qui in the same contexts but it is quite marked.

Comment: Take care though that _Qu'_ only stands for _'Que'_ before a vowel. However the ***-i*** in _Qui_ is never dropped even when it comes before a vowel. Notice this sentence: _C'est toi ***qui*** es responsible ._ Not ~C'est toi ***qu'*** es responsible.~ So _qu'_ is ***only*** a contraction of _Que_ .

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence
Dans ta phrase :

> Il a attendu un bus *qui* n'est jamais arrivé.

We are using **qui** as a relative pronoun to refer to the subject in the relative clause.
On utilise **qui** en *pronom relatif* pour désigner le sujet dans la proposition relative.

---

As @oldergod says, we only use **qu'** and not *"que"* when the first letter in the next word is a vowel.
Comme l'indique @oldergod, on utilise **qu'** à la place de *"que"* quand la première lettre du prochain mot est une voyelle.

---

If you want more information about which one to use, clic on the links : [que](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Fran.C3.A7ais) and [qui](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui#Fran.C3.A7ais).
Si tu veux savoir lequel utiliser entre [que](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Fran.C3.A7ais) et [qui](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui#Fran.C3.A7ais), clique sur les liens.

Answer (score 1):

You use "qui" when it refers to the subject :

> Le chanteur qui a écrit ça
>
> Un bus qui n'est jamais arrivé (parce que c'est un bus de la RATP)

You use "que" when it refers to the direct object complement (COD) :

> La maison que le maçon portugais a construite.

If the indirect object complement (COI) you refer to is a person or animal, you will use "à qui".

> L'homme à qui elle a pensé

If the indirect object complement (COI) you refer to is neither a person nor an animal, you will use "auquel" (masc.) or "à laquelle" (fem.).

> La maison à laquelle on a donné un petit coup de jeune.

«Qu'» is just "que" before a word starting by a vowel.

> La maison qu'il a construite.